# Date comparison shows the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Tags: android

I want to compare two dates. I entered both dates in `dd-MM-yyyy` format as string. `d1` and `d2` are two string dates. Here is my code:

```
try {
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

            date1 = sdf.parse(d1);
            date2 = sdf.parse(d2);

            if (date1.after(date2)) {
                System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
            }

            if (date1.before(date2)) {
                System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
            }


            if (date1.equals(date2)) {
                System.out.println("Date1 is equal Date2");
            }

            System.out.println();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Could you give the two date strings that cause the error?

Comment: d1=29-04-2019,d2=24-05-2019. these are two  strings

Comment: Passing in the strings as literals (`Date date1 = sdf.parse("29-04-2019");`) is working fine for me. If that works for you as well, `d1` and `d2` may not be what you think they are...